# The efficiency of looping over nested dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.x, hash-map

How to make the following code more efficient?

```
"""
Calculate the posterior distribution of p(pos|word) using Baye's rule:
p(pos|word) \propto p(word|pos)p(pos).
"""    
word_pos_dict = defaultdict(float)  # Example, word|pos -> 0.0012
pos_dict = defaultdict(float)       # pos -> 0.005
pos_word_dict = defaultdict(float)  # pos|word -> 0.017

for word_pos, word_pos_prob in word_pos_dict.items():
    word, pos = word_pos.split('|')
    marginal_prob = 0        
    for pos_prob in pos_dict.values():
        marginal_prob += word_pos_prob * pos_prob    # Marginal prob of p(word)
    pos_word_prob = word_pos_prob * pos_dict[pos]
    pos_word = pos + '|' + word
    pos_word_dict[pos_word] = pos_word_prob / marginal_prob
```

In practice, the length of `word_pos_dict` is 57,602, and `pos_dict` has 984 elements, which make this calculation much slower. Is there something wrong with the implementation, design or algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One obvious improvement:

```
for word_pos, word_pos_prob in word_pos_dict.items():
    marginal_prob = 0        
    for pos_prob in pos_dict.values():
        marginal_prob += word_pos_prob * pos_prob
```

Simplifies to:

```
multiplier = 0
for pos_prob in pos_dict.values():
    multiplier += pos_prob
# or just 'multiplier = sum(pos_dict.values())'

for word_pos, word_pos_prob in word_pos_dict.items():
    marginal_prob = word_pos_prob * multiplier
```

Now the inner loop only runs once.

Answer (score 4):

> which make this calculation much slower.

An immediate question is *much slower than what?*

Few optimisations are obvious, but they are just nitpicking. Asymptotics remains same no matter what.

First, I'd make `word_pos_dict` indices tuples instead of string. That would save you string splitting and concatenation.

Second, swapping inner/outer loops in your case would be beneficial: as coded, you initialize inner loop 57602 times; when swapped, the initialization would happen only 984 times.

Comment: Sorry for the vague expression. I thought that it would be executed in minutes but hours.

Comment: I have to say that using tuples instead of string is a beautiful solution but it will cost more time.